# Assigning unique numbers to combinations of columns with repeating values

Tags: excel

I have a sample csv/excel columns that look like below.

| Condition | Subreplicate |
| --- | --- |
| C | 1 |
| Ctrl | 3 |
| C | 2 |
| T+C | 1 |
| T+C | 1 |
| Ctrl | 2 |
| C | 2 |
| T+C | 2 |

I want to make a new column called "Replicate" that counts the combination of these 2 columns in order. I want this "Replicate" column to assign unique number for these column repeats, because I have to analyze them individually. Each row is unique data points. The counting should be based on the combination of the first two columns: Conditions and Subreplicates.

For example, if I have 6 total "C and 1" combination, the Replicate column should be ascending from 1-6. Then find "C and 2" combination and count onward from 7-upward. Same goes with T+C. I want to count "T+C and 1" first, the "T+C and 2" next. Even if "Ctrl and 3" shows up first in the excel, I want to count up starting from "Ctrl and 1" first.

I've created an example column below. "Ctrl and 3" starts from 21 because way down in the dataframe, there are lots of "Ctrl and 1" and "Ctrl and 2".

| Condition | Subreplicate | Replicate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 1 | 1 |
| Ctrl | 3 | 21 |
| C | 2 | 2 |
| T+C | 1 | 1 |
| T+C | 1 | 2 |
| Ctrl | 2 | 20 |
| C | 2 | 3 |
| T+C | 2 | 3 |

I hope I'm making sense. I have been very stuck, any help would be great. Thank you for your time!

Edit: Provided data via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) instead of images.
Edit: Fixed confusing language problem.

Comment: Please provide your data via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) - then it is much easier to help you

Comment: Please review your question, the expected output counts by first column, but the explanation suggests to count by the combination of the first two columns. Both problems can be solved in a very similar way (check my answer), but for a better understanding of the problem, better to have the information consistent.

Comment: Tip for your next question, there is no need to show so many rows to explain your point, it makes your question unnecessary too large.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have edited accordingly. `A1:A20 & B1:B20` suggestion worked beautifully. 1 question. 1) Could you show me how to count by the combination of the first two columns? Thank you

Comment: @CeC I guess this comments is related to my answer, not to your question. About your question I am confused. Using the concatenation in my formula is how it is supposed to count for a combination of both columns.

Comment: I thought it was clear how to adapt my initial approach, if not here is what I meant: `=LET(AB, A1:A20&"-"&B1:B20, seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(AB)), srt, SORT(HSTACK(AB, seq)), sAB, INDEX(srt,,1), cnts, SCAN("", seq, LAMBDA(ac,s, IF(ac="", 1, IF(INDEX(sAB, s) = INDEX(sAB, s-1), ac+1, 1)))), SORTBY(cnts, INDEX(srt,,2)))` I replaced `A` with `AB`, but this is just have a more meaningful name

Comment: Yes, your language was clear. I'm not sure how to change your code to count "Ctrl and 1" first (as in giving it lower Replicate number), then "Ctrl and 3", even though "Ctrl and 3" appears first in the csv file. For example, the output picture below shows "Ctrl and 3" as 1,2,3 but they should be counted later.

Comment: @CeC I guess I understood what you mean. You want to count by column `A`but sort also considering the column `B`. Please check the formula labeled as *Formula 2* in my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is to sort the data (`srt`), so we can count consecutive repeated values, but having a way to go back to the original sort (`seq`). You can try the following formula in cell `D1` (*Formula 1*):

```
=LET(A, A1:A20, seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)), srt, SORT(HSTACK(A, seq)), 
  sA, INDEX(srt,,1), cnts, SCAN("", seq, LAMBDA(ac, s, IF(ac="", 1, 
    IF(INDEX(sA, s) = INDEX(sA, s-1), ac+1, 1)))), SORTBY(cnts, INDEX(srt,,2)))
```

Where `sA` represents the column `A` sorted. We count via `SCAN` function consecutive repeated values and name it `cnts`. Then we just put `cnts` in the original order via `SORTBY` function.

Here is the output:
[image: output formula 1]

If you want to count only the first column but you want consider as sorting criteria first column **A**, and then column **B**, then you can adapt the previous formula as follow (*Formula 2*):

```
=LET(A, A1:A20, B, B1:B20, seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)), 
  srt, SORT(HSTACK(A,B, seq), {1,2}), sA, INDEX(srt,,1), cnts, SCAN("", seq, 
    LAMBDA(ac,s, IF(ac="", 1, IF(INDEX(sA, s) = INDEX(sA, s-1), ac+1, 1)))), 
  SORTBY(cnts, INDEX(srt,,3)))
```

Notice we use `SORT` indicating as sorting criteria  `{1,2}`. We sort first by column **A**, then by column **B**.

Here is the output (notice the highlighted rows where we change the order to show it works)
[image: output formula 2]

If you want to do the count based on the first two columns, then just use as input the concatenation of the first two columns. For example (*Formula 3*):

```
=LET(AB, A1:A20&"-"&B1:B20,seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(AB)), srt, SORT(HSTACK(AB, seq)), 
 sAB, INDEX(srt,,1), cnts, SCAN("", seq, LAMBDA(ac,s, IF(ac="", 1, 
  IF(INDEX(sAB, s) = INDEX(sAB, s-1), ac+1, 1)))), SORTBY(cnts, INDEX(srt,,2)))
```

Here is the output (counting based on concatenation of the first two columns):
[image: output formula 3]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this out, and update you on the result! Can this have more conditions added to it? For example, if I had `Group` (column `C`) and `Target` (column `D`) columns, and want to select these columns before `Condition` column (column `A`) in this case.